# Adding element to list by user

Tags: python, python-2.7

I cannot add all elements in the list. Just last element added. How can I add all entered elements ?

```
N = input("Enter the number of elemets: ")
for i in xrange(N):
    N = []
    a = input('%d. Element: ' %(i+1))
    N.append(a)    
print N
```

Comment: You should **not** reset `N` all the time.

Comment: `N = []` is emptying the list each iteration of the `for`-loop. Move the line `N = []` before entering the `for`-loop, and rename `N` to a different variable name that is not already used on the first line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are resetting `N` to an empty list on each iteration of the `for`-loop, then on the last iteration the last `a` value gets appended to the empty list, thus finishing with only one item in the `N` list.

Also, use a different variable name for the list (not the same variable that you defined for the input `N`)

```
N = input("Enter the number of elemets: ")
n = []                   # use a different variable name for this list
for i in xrange(int(N)): # cast N to integer
    a = input('%d. Element: ' %(i+1))
    n.append(a)          # append to the list `n` not `N`
print n                  # print the list
```

sample run:

```
Enter the number of elemets: 5
1. Element: 3
2. Element: 4
3. Element: 6
4. Element: 7
5. Element: 8
['3', '4', '6', '7', '8']
```